# Use python zlib to decompress string compressed with javascript zlib

Tags: javascript, python, zlib

On the client side, I use the [zlib.js](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js/blob/develop/README.en.md) library to deflate some string, then I encode it into base64 to be sent to the server:

```
var a = {"foo" : "bar"};
var deflate = new Zlib.Deflate(JSON.stringify(a));
var compressed = deflate.compress();
var sentToServer = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, compressed));
>>> "eJwVwwEJAAAAgKD/ry3B5QAdegQ0"
```

On the server side I want to use [zlib for python27](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) to decompress, but I got the following error:

```
import base64, zlib

a = base64.b4decode("eJwVwwEJAAAAgKD/ry3B5QAdegQ0")
zlib.decompress(a)
>>>zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back
```

What is the proper way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zlib.js`'s `Deflate` accepts `Array.<number>` or`Uint8Array`, you need convert JSON to an array of int:

```
var a = {"foo" : "bar"};
var s = JSON.stringify(a);
var data = new Array(s.length);
for (i = 0, il = s.length; i < il; ++i) {
    data[i] = s.charCodeAt(i);
}
var deflate = new Zlib.Deflate(data);
```

which yields: `eJwFgEEJAAAIA7tcDNvow+/A77D7MCtRTB8fHXoENA==`